# Button not inlined on smaller devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form that looks like this (on a big device, e.g. pc monitor)

[image: Screenshot]

that is as it should be. On smaller devices it however looks like this:

[image]

the button is no longer in the same line as the input. My code looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Title</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" autocomplete="off" name="title" type="text" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <a id="btn-verify" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Verify</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I ensure that it also is aligned correctly when using smaller devices? 
PS: Bootstrap is being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your columns are `col-md`, which means that when the screen width gets below 992px, the columns will take up the full width of the page. So if you want them to stay inline, then add `col-xs` classes with the column sizes that you need.

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group ">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Title</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <input id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" autocomplete="off" name="title" type="text" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <a id="btn-verify" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Verify</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the input and button need to be set to display: inline, and they should be placed in the same column. Below works and should satisfy your needs:

```html
<div class="form-group ">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Title</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md">
                <input id="title" class="form-control d-inline w-70 float-left" placeholder="Title" autocomplete="off" name="title" type="text" value="">
                <a id="btn-verify" class="btn btn-primary float-left d-inline">Verify</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stacking the bootstrap col classes?

The lg / md / sm all target different screen size thresholds. Using multiples should help you define the space it should take up in a given scenario. I would say you can steal some real-estate from that input.

You could also consider putting them in the same div.

Your code modified with stacked col classes:

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Title</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-6">
                <input id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" autocomplete="off" name="title" type="text" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                <a id="btn-verify" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Verify</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```